# jquery button not working with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

HTML CODE :

```
<input type="button" id="close" class"close_tag">
```

jQuery Code:

close id is working fine and
close id is associated many functions

```
 $(document).on('click','#close',function(){
   works very fine...
    action is performed successfully .
});
```

but this one won"t work

```
  $(document).on('click','.close_tag',function(){

    don:t perform any specific actions.
});
```

Comment: You're missing an `=` after class. It should be `class="close_tag"`.

Comment: You seem to be missing a `=` in your `<input>` tag. It should be `class="close_tag"`.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work since your HTML has a typo in it

```
<input type="button" id="close" class"close_tag">
                                     ^
```

should be

```
<input type="button" id="close" class="close_tag">
                                     ^
```

Comment: ya in my code it is <input type="button" id="close" class="close_tag">

Comment: Than you have a problem that is not shown in the code you provided. Since all the answers are based off the typo in your code. You might as well delete this, start over with more code that that shows the issue and use the real code so you do not have typos.

Answer (score 0):

**Change this**

`<input type="button" id="close" class"close_tag">`

**To**

```
<input type="button" id="close" class="close_tag">
```

class="close_tag" not class"close_tag"

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/xrxjqhbm/)

Comment: ya in my code it is same <input type="button" id="close" class"close_tag"> but wont work

Comment: Change `class"close_tag"` to `class="close_tag"` .you forgot `=` to assign class

Comment: Add your full html & js ,maybe the problem is somewhere else :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to fix your button (just add equal)

```
<input type="button" id="close" class="close_tag">
```